# How to solve data frame bbject not found error in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a problem with a data frame which leads to the error message 
"object not found".

I define two functions, Mom and ExpB, where ExpB is called in main 
itself calls Mom. Mom defines the object "Out" which is not found. 
Here are the relevant code parts:

```
Mom <- function(x){ 
  Out.data = data.frame( 
    m  = mean(x),
    sx = sqrt( mean(x^2) - mean(x)^2 ),
    se = sqrt( mean(x^2) - mean(x)^2 ) / sqrt( length(x) )
  ) 
  return(Out)
}

ExpB <- function(Inp) {
    ...
    dA  = seq(1,ns)*0
    ...
    dA_mom = Mom(dA);   
    ...
}
```

The line
    Out = ExpB(Inp)
in main leads to the message: 
"Error in Mom(dA) : object 'Out' not found".

Comment: Looks like Mom should return Out.data, not Out. Inside the body of Mom, you don't define an object called Out.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment. Note that without seeing the full definition of ExpB, it's hard to know if this is everything. Inside the body of `Mom`, you create a new object called `Out.data`. However, `Mom` tires to return an object called `Out`. There is not object `Out` being defined inside `Mom`, so R tells you that it can't find an object called `Out`. Changing `Out` to `Out.data` in the `return` call will fix the issue, as I demonstrate below in `Mom2`.

```
> vec <- rnorm(10)
> 
> Mom1 <- function(x){ 
+   Out.data = data.frame( 
+     m  = mean(x),
+     sx = sqrt( mean(x^2) - mean(x)^2 ),
+     se = sqrt( mean(x^2) - mean(x)^2 ) / sqrt( length(x) )
+   ) 
+   return(Out)
+ }
> 
> Mom1(vec)
Error in Mom1(vec) : object 'Out' not found
> 
> Mom2 <- function(x){ 
+   Out.data = data.frame( 
+     m  = mean(x),
+     sx = sqrt( mean(x^2) - mean(x)^2 ),
+     se = sqrt( mean(x^2) - mean(x)^2 ) / sqrt( length(x) )
+   ) 
+   return(Out.data)
+ }
> 
> Mom2(vec)
          m       sx        se
1 0.1080265 1.111821 0.3515887
```